# how to make brew output log in terminal

Tags: nginx, homebrew

I am using this command to start nginx on macOS (M1 chip):

```
brew services nginx start
```

the output tell me the service start success, but when I using this commnad to check the services and check the listening port, did not found the service.

```
ps -aux|grep nginx
lsof -i:8084
```

and I check the log from `/opt/homebrew/var/log/nginx` access.log/error.log still no new information output. what should I do to know the brew service encount problem? what should I do to know the point of where is going wrong?